# Pass parameter into controller - autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Have a rails app that is supposed to display a list of products/managers. After searching high and low I have had responses and found that I need to pass a paremeter into my controller that contains the list.

```
    def manager_list  
    list=User.all.map{|i|i.full_name}
    arr= [].concat(list.sort{|a,b| a[0]<=>b[0]}).to_json
    render :json =>arr
  end
```

**Javascript**

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "/managerlist",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var results = [];
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    var itemToAdd = {
                        value: item,
                        label: item
                    };
                    results.push(itemToAdd);
                });
                return response(results);
```

My knowledge of ruby and javascript is not to the highest. However I do know that the following list=User.all.map. Is gathering all the users full_name and concatenating it. What I have been trying for hours on is figuring out how to exactly pass the var 'term' as a parameter into my user controller. So that when I run the rails app and search for a specific manager or product it will display a singal record and not the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you are trying to implement the auto-complete feature, I presume you search for names starting with a given pattern.

The controller would look something like this:

```
def manager_list  
  matching_users = User.where(['full_name like ?', "#{params[:term]}%"])
  matching_names = [].concat(matching_users.map(&:full_name).sort{|a,b| a[0]<=> b[0]}).to_json
  render :json => matching_names 
end
```

Also, the  `term: request.term` does not sound right to me. I am not sure, where you are fetching the search term from your UI. Please verify that.

Answer (score 0):

Does you manager_list method inside a Controller?

Here is what your controller might look like:

```
class UserController < ActionController::Base

  def manager_list
    var term = params[:term]
    ... // work with your parameter
  end
end
```

If you should only get 1 result from this... i would rename it getManager instead, since you wont get a list.

if term is a field in your User Model, there is a dynamic finder you can call!!
something like this:

```
User.find_by_term!(term)
```

Hope i answered your question!

Regards